# loop through a Pandas dataframe and add annotation

Tags: pandas, append

I am trying to add annotations to a dataframe based on values in different columns. Here is the data for my plant sale:

```
     UPC  Quantity       Name    Size   Color       Type
0  11313        68     Crocus   small  purple  perennial
1  42164        51  Sunflower   large  yellow     annual
2  53890        76     Zinnia   small    pink     annual
3  54885        85      Daisy  medium   white  perennial
4  77314        80       Rose   large     red  perennial
5  79375        62        Mum  medium  yellow     annual
6  94281         1    Dahlia    large  orange  perennial
7  95085        41   Marigold   small  orange     annual

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Plants_in_stock.csv")
#I add a column to annotate a discount for products I want to move
df['Discount'] = ''
df
```

[This is what the output looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9gIZ.png)

Now I want to append the 'Discount' column to say 25% if 'Quantity'>80 and 50% if 'Type' == 'annual'.

How should I proceed?

Comment: And what happens if Quantity > 80 AND Type == 'annual', given that these don't appear to be mutually exclusive conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.select`:

```
conds = [df.Quantity > 80, df['Type'] == 'annual']

choices = [0.25,0.5]
# or if you prefer strings formated with %:
# choices = ['25%','50%']

df['discount'] = pd.np.select(conds, choices)

>>> df
     UPC  Quantity       Name    Size   Color       Type  discount
0  11313        68     Crocus   small  purple  perennial      0.00
1  42164        51  Sunflower   large  yellow     annual      0.50
2  53890        76     Zinnia   small    pink     annual      0.50
3  54885        85      Daisy  medium   white  perennial      0.25
4  77314        80       Rose   large     red  perennial      0.00
5  79375        62        Mum  medium  yellow     annual      0.50
6  94281         1    Dahlia    large  orange  perennial      0.00
7  95085        41   Marigold   small  orange     annual      0.50
```